# Power Pivot Max Value Selected In Slicer

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, powerpivot

I have the following slicer in excel and the users select more than one option

[image]

How can I get with DAX the maximum value selected in the slicer? and save it in a variable

with the example I should get the value 4

I have tried the following formula but I get an error
**MAX(VALUES(Table1[period]))**

Comment: What exactly do you mean save it in a variable?  If you are trying to use it in a measure it would be

Measure1:=var maxSelected = MAX(Table1[period]) RETURN (rest of measure)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this Measure to get Max of selected values in a slicer.

[image]